# Add database rows from CSV with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE and add a field that is unique for each row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a query that inserts database rows from a .csv file and then fills one field with a randomly generated string. This is the code I'm using:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]."'
        INTO TABLE mailinglist
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
        (name, email)
        SET unsubscribe = '".substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,30)."'";

$db = dbConnection();

$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
```

The problem I'm having is that the unsubscribe field is filled with the same randomly generated string in each row while it should generate another one for each new row. How can I fix it so it does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let mysql do the job instead of php, using built-in [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]."'
        INTO TABLE mailinglist
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
        (name, email)
        SET unsubscribe = SUBSTRING(REPLACE(UUID(),"-",""),0,30)";
```

or better just:

```
        SET unsubscribe = UUID()";
```

Comment: @FrankKluyt you are welcome; pls note that this UUID function has randomness, but not real unpredictability; so I though for your scenario would be safe enough, but keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

use str_random('dddd CC'); function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
concat(
  substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',rand(@seed:=round(rand(LAST_INSERT_ID())*4294967296))*3 6+1, 1),
  substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
  substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', rand(@seed)*36+1, 1)
)
```

It will generate a random string with the length of 3. Just reuse the middle substring multiple times to advance.

EDIT:

If you don't need real randomness, you could use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.uniqid.php)